# Is there any way we can automate desktop applications using cypress .. Any Plug in or tool available?

Tags: cypress, desktop-application

Is there any way we can automate desktop applications using cypress .. Any Plug in or tool available ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, desktop app automation is not possible with cypress or with any cypress plugin.

Cypress code for interacting with elements runs inside the browser, which makes it impossible to interact with anything outside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tools https://github.com/clicknium/clicknium-docs. It can automate both desktop application and web application.